# How to make a typwriter animation in CSS responsive?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors, css-animations

I've managed that it works in one line when the screen is desktop size. But I just can't manage to make it go into multiple rows when I make the screen size smaller.

I know that I can just make the text smaller with media queries, but honestly it just looks weird if it stays in one line.

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-video-wrapper">
    <div class="typewriter">
    <h1>Budi izvrstan u onom što voliš.</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-video-wrapper h1{
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 50rem;
    height: 3rem;
    color: var(--white-color);
    text-align: center;
}

/* typing animation - budi izvrstan*/
.typewriter h1{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--yellow-color);
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    animation: 
        typing 7s steps(40, end) infinite,
        blink-cursor .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from{
        width: 0;
    }
    to{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-cursor {
    from, to {border-color: transparent;}
    50%{border-color: var(--yellow-color);}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I tried and it is breaking the sentence into 2 rows on small screens and working animation.

**Updated CSS Code**

```
.bg-video-wrapper h1 {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 50rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--yellow-color);
  animation: typing 7s steps(40, end) infinite, blink-cursor 0.75s step-end infinite;
}

/* Media query for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .typewriter h1 {
    height: 6rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work. the animation just starts again when it gets to the edge of the screen. It is still only in one row. The background for this text animation is a video that has an overlay. Is it possible that for some reason that produces problems?

Comment: @AntonelaAbičić I do not understand your comment properly. Can you share some code or maybe a Codepen link or something else? So, I can check it and help you in a much better way

Comment: I really appreciate it that you want to help me. This is my first major project and I'd really could use some help. When I make my screen smaller, instead of the text staying only in a single row, I want it to break into multiple rows as is needed. This is the Github link: https://github.com/antonelaabicic/SUPIT-project

Comment: @Advil What do you mean? I've checked github and nothing new was added since I put it up 5 days ago? What exactly have you done?

Comment: @AntonelaAbičić I updated my code in the answer here, I am not allowed to push in your repository. That's why.